# matlab ode15s doesn't work when called within GA

Tags: genetic-algorithm, matlab, ode, differential-equations

I have a mathematical (parametric) model of a bushing. The input to the model is displacement(sine wave) with force as output(at respective timesteps).

The parameters of the model are to be identified using GA and the force equation is to be solved using ode15s solver.

The solver gives the output when a set of parameters are assumed (without using GA) but when called from GA i get the following error `n` no.of times:

> Warning: Matrix is singular, close to singular or badly scaled.
>   Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = NaN.

and finally

> Warning: Failure at t=1.570796e+000.  Unable to meet integration
>   tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value
>   allowed (3.552714e-015) at time t.

I am a little puzzled since the code works fine without using GA and not with GA. I would be really thankful for your inputs.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Code :
Main call

```
ga_custom={@GA_test,measurement_data,excitation};
[x,fval,exitflag,output,population,scores]=ga(ga_custom,no_of_vars,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

GA_test function:

```
function error_fnc = GA_test(x,measurement_data,excitation)
error_fnc=0;   
F=my_force_Curve(excitation,x);    
for q=1:100  
    temp=(F(q)-measurement_data(q))^2;  
    error_fnc=error_fnc+temp;   
end   
end
```

`my_force_Curve` calculates force for individual models:

```
[T,y]=ode15s(@(T,y)differential_BW(T,y,x),tspan,[0 0 0 0]);
```

and `differential_BW` solves the equations:

```
function dy=differential_BW(t,y,initial_guess)   
dy=zeros(4,1);
dy(1)=..
dy(2)=.. 
dy(3)=..
dy(4)=..
```

Apologies if its too lengthy.

Thanks again.

Comment: did you write the GA yourself?  I've used a GA (that I wrote) with matlab's ode45 before and had no problems. The system I was using was highly sensitive to initial conditions (chaotic).

Anyway, point being, I think this is a situational thing, so you're going to have to show us the code or provide more details (and please don't just post a big wall of code... nobody wants to work through that; try to focus your problem down to a couple lines of code with debugging.)

Comment: why do you need to use ode15s? Are you sure your equation is stiff?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs first of all.It is a stiff diff.equation since i need to get hysteresis curves. @Xurtio : I did not use my own GA. I have edited my question and posted my code snippet.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me that for some parameters, the ODE solver cannot solve the equation.

I can see two possible causes for this:

1. Your GA may evaluate different members of the population in parallel. If you use global or persistent values that may change depending on the parameters or the run, this causes indeterministic behavior, which can cause non-convergence. You can tackle this by either refactoring those `global`/`persistent` variables and passing these values in another fashion. The other solution is to make sure the GA runs everything in serial. This can be done by setting `UseParallel` to `'never'` with `gaoptimset` (which is the default option anyway).
2. Your ODE does not converge for certain parameter values. This has nothing to do with the GA itself. If you were to try the parameter values the GA chose at some point and repeated the run manually, you should get the same problem. What I'd try to do is, put a `try ... catch` around your ODE solver and check for convergence issues. If it doesn't converge, you can do several things:

   - Just report the parameter values or save them somewhere. That way you can check for yourself what happens at that point by running your objective/ODE manually. This should give the same problem, but there you can at least try to debug everything. If you find e.g. that some parameters are incompatible, you can check for that and return an unfavorable value for your objective (`0` or perhaps `NaN`).
   - Just directly return an unfavorable value for the objective function. That way, the search can continue and it will not select that point during mutation. However, it is a bit of a hack if you don't know why those parameter values don't converge properly.

Comment: Hi,  I will try to use `global/persistent` variables and let u know.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sat0408: No, the message was NOT to use those. They make running in parallel and testing your code hard to near impossible.

Comment: Another caveat.  If you interrupt and restart an ODEsolver on a sensitive (chaotic) system using the event handler, you will have nondeterministic results as well.  I had to download mathwork's ode4.m wehich is a fixed-step integrator.  The other ones all use interpolation and change step size depending on tolerance values.  This works great to speed up code for non-sensitive systems, but once you have a chaotic system, it will lead to inocnsistent results.

Comment: @Egon : The `try..catch` around the solver helped me a lot and i avoided some parameters tat gave me vague/non-converging results.     Thanks a ton :)